# Define a function in python which returns if the number is in the range say 1,000 to 10,000. But the catch is I have to do it in one line only

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, boolean

```py
def RangeChecker(num):
    if num in range(1000, 10001):
        return True
    return False
x = RangeChecker(500)
```

This is my code , how do I change the function to a single return statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply return the condition itself as it evaluates to the exact boolean value you want to return:

```
def RangeChecker(num):
    return num in range(...)
```

If you want to allow non-integers and understand "range" in a more natural language way, you could go with comparison operator chaining:

```
def RangeChecker(num):
    return 1000 <= num <= 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite your `if` to a single line with `else`:

```
def RangeChecker(num):
    return True if num in range(1000, 100001) else False
```